# How to address program hanging with no error, possibly related to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, json, pyaudio, google-cloud-speech

Here is a snippet of the code I am working with. The program correctly records the audio from the microphone and makes a file from it. Then when you press "STOP RECORDING" it all goes blank and hangs there spitting out "Is it getting stuck here" a million times, and eventually my Mac fans start kicking in (is this a memory leak?). I want it to get to the next part of my program (which all *should* work). What should I do to fix this and get my program running? I **THINK** it may involve the .json file that I'm using, but again, I don't know how to fix it even if it was the underlying issue. Any help would be appreciated.

*Addendum: I am porting this program over from Windows to my Mac and am trying to also make sure that there are no compatibility issues. The program is being written in Python with PyCharm (it was running in the same version of PyCharm in Windows as well.)*

```
import os
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from google.cloud import storage
from PyAudio import RecAUD
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech

numberOfSpeakers = int(input("Please enter number of speakers (up to 6 people may participate): "))
chosenSpeaker = int(input("Please enter the # of the speaker to be analyzed: "))

guiAUD = RecAUD()

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'Users/davidkarimi/PycharmProjects/ATWM/Project ATWM-a83e05b28663.json'

def create_bucket(bucket_name):
    """Creates a new bucket."""

    print("Is it getting stuck here?")
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.create_bucket(bucket_name)
    print('Bucket {} created'.format(bucket.name))  ## have program automatically name new buckets in unique ways to prevent naming conflicts
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? PyCharm has a debugger, but even some print statements could help.

Comment: Yes...well...So - that's the rub. As it's hanging, I attempt to stop the program in hopes that some sort of error will guide me to the problem. Alas, nothing shows up when I press "STOP". It just shows: `Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)` and that's it. I'm thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this will work on Mac `from PyAudio import RecAUD`.
The folowing code was working for me on Mac.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
from google.cloud import storage

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "file.wav"

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# start Recording
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print( "recording...")
frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
print ("finished recording")


# stop Recording
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
audio.terminate()

waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
waveFile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
waveFile.setframerate(RATE)
waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
waveFile.close()

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'key.json'


storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.create_bucket("bucket-name")
print("Bucket Created {}".format(bucket.name))
```